# Assigning pointers - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, variables, pointers

in the past I have mostly been programming in .NET and because of that I haven't had to worry about things like pointers especially much but recently I have gotten into Objective-C and I have decided to try and fully understand the workings of memory management.

So, first I'd like to say I know you shouldn't make pointers for int's as it doesn't help efficiency but this is mostly an experiment out of curiosity.

If I create an integer pointer as such:
    int *intPointer;
How comes that it's actually the memory location that the pointer is pointing to that gets assigned when I do:

```
intPointer = 43;
```

As I have understood it, shouldn't such an action be changing the actual memory address of the pointer?

The same goes for this piece of code:

```
int *intPointer;
int integer;

integer = 43;
intPointer = integer;
```

Same result, but when I was working with CLLocationCoordinate2D and tried to make a pointer point to an CLLocationCoordinate2D variable, I actually had to do:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D *coordinatePointer = &coordinate;
```

Which to me seems to be the correct way.

This is my first post here on stackoverflow and I hope it was good enough to be answered.
Thank you!

Comment: I recommend getting the ebook by Bill Dudney, All the C You Need To Know in iBooks store. That will give you a good C intro with Objective-C in mind.

Comment: Bad code smell smells bad.  You pretty much never use the & operator in objective-c.

Comment: @bbum - Pretty much never? `NSError **` ...

Comment: You should never say `intPointer = 43;`.  That is assigning a bogus value to the pointer, rendering the pointer no longer a valid pointer.  (Read some good C books before you do any more programming -- PLEASE.)

Comment: @CRD his point is that out parameters are a rarity.  When was the last time you used a non-error related out object parameter (for a good reason)?  C uses them like crazy for counts and simulating multiple returns.

Comment: @CRD Exactly what CodFi said;  `NSError**` is the only common use of pass by reference and use beyond that is exceedingly rare.

Comment: @bbum & codafi - I agree with both of you: With the notable exception of `NSError *` variables used as out parameters the use of `&` is uncommon. However that pattern is not *rare*, I was justing hinting a clarification might be in order, rather than myself “correcting” a giant ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
intPointer = integer;
```

This only works because of implicit conversion. Pointer is just a memory offset, which is numeric, so it can be assigned from an int (and you should get compiler warning about that).

In case of CLLocationCoordinate2D, struct cannot be converted to pointer, so compiler reports error. And when you write `&coordinate`, it gives a reference to variable `coordinate` which pointer can be assigned to.

Comment: So does implicit conversion turn `intPointer = integer` to something like `intPointer = &integer` or is that code actually changing the memory offset of the pointer? I checked the value of what `intPointer` was pointing at, and it did assign it correctly when I was using `intPointer = integer`.

Comment: Both `intPointer = &integer` and `intPointer = integer` are just changing offset intPointer is pointing to. The only difference is value intPointer will have in the end. In the first case (`&integer`) it will point to the `integer` variable, so `*intPointer = 42` will write 42 into `integer` variable. In the second case it will be pointing to memory address 43 (value of variable `integer`), so writing `*intPointer = 42` most likely will raise bad access exception, because you cannot write into any random address.

Comment: @FabianLindfors - The above answer gives the impression that assigning an integer to a pointer is OK.  It's not.  You should *never* do this (at least not until you *really* understand what's going on and realize why it's a terrible idea).

Answer (score 1):

Your initial assumption that is is working, is false:

intPointer = integer;

What actually is happening that if you store 10 in variable "integer", then it will get copied in intPointer. So when you will try to get value from intPointer using *intPointer, it will give you the value stored at memory 10, which could be anything. But if you do this:

intPointer = &integer;

Only then the memory of integer will get stored in intPointer.Then later on if you do this:

integer = 60;

then *intPointer will also give you 60.
In other words, intPointer will have the memory address of integer, hence will be pointing to integer.

Comment: Thank you for such fast and consistent answers, programming can really be a pain especially when you've been doing it for so long but still don't know basic stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

The question that you asked was all about plain C pointers. Objective-C is C with additions (there is also Objective-C++ which is C++ with additions). When you write code with Xcode, you can decide what warnings the compiler gives you and whether these warnings should be treated as errors. With lowest warnings settings, the compiler will accept code that it absolutely shouldn't accept. In your example

```
int *intPointer;
int integer;

integer = 43;
intPointer = integer;
```

the second assignment will not compile with any sane build settings for the compiler (but it may be possible to set the build settings to make it compile. Check what warnings you got). The proper way to do this would be

```
intPointer = &integer;
```

intPointer = integer, if you convince the compiler to compile it, would take the number 43 and interpret it as a pointer. Since it is highly likely that there is anything sensible stored at memory location 43, using intPointer to read or write an int is most likely to crash. intPointer = &integer takes the address of the variable "integer" and stores it in the pointer intPointer. Now the value of "intPointer" is the address of integer, and the value of *intPointer is the contents of "integer" that is 43.

Learning about Objective-C objects is the next step.